# Shell sort algorithm does not finish

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, shellsort

I have a problem with my shell sort algorithm. It is a vector of 50 numbers and want to sort it in increasing order. It works' fine at start but when the gap = 1 it just iterates one time and then stop. I think it has something to do with the `while(inner < getElementCount()- gap){` condition, because I want it to iterate until the vector is sorted. I have been struggling with this for the last hours and really need som help!

```
public void shellSort() {
    int inner = 0;
    int outer = 0;
    float gap = getElementCount()/(float)2.2;

    while(inner < getElementCount()- gap) {
        for(inner = 0; inner < getElementCount() - gap; inner++) {
            outer = inner + (int)gap;
            if(cmp(outer,inner)< 0) {
                swap(outer,inner);
            }
            else {
                while(cmp(outer,inner) > 0) {
                    outer--;
                }
                if(gap!=1 && inner < outer) {
                    swap(outer,inner);
                }
            }
        }
        if(gap <= 2.2) {
            gap = 1;
        }
        else {
            gap = gap/(float)2.2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can the "while" condition return false if the inner loop never increases "inner" beyond "getElementCount() - gap"?

Comment: Errr is this `shell` related to the tag `shell`?

Comment: Apparently not. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with `while(inner < getElementCount()- gap){`

Yes you are right it would have worked for first loop, but when it goes into for loop. you increment inner variable and once it doesn't satisfy `inner < getElementCount() - gap`, it break from for loop and then checks while loop to loop further and sees that it doesn't `inner < getElementCount() - gap` hence comes out of while loop as well.

I would suggest you replace while with something like a for loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<getElementCount()/2; i++)
```

Comment: That works, but the problem is that its kind of "cheat" solution. The algorithm keeps comparing the array even though the sorting is complete. We want the algortihm to jump out of the loop the second the sorting is complete

Comment: If that's the case then keep a check on swap if there are no more swap taking place then you might be done with sorting (but might not be full proof).